# How can I use UTF-8 with org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient create()?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, cxf, webclient

This is about Apache CXF　`WebClient`,
`WebClient.create("URL", "username", "password", null);`

when I use a UTF-8 username to create a WebClient instance, I ended up with a 401 http error.

I've tried `WebClient.encoding("UTF-8“)`, and `WebClient.acceptLanguage("zh_CN")`, but neither worked.

Any idea or help is appreciated. Thanks.